# Not been Able to Build Production Build for my ionic 2 app

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to build the production build for my ionic app. Everything works fine if am running my app with:

> ***ionic run android***

But when i am trying to build my production app by using

> ***ionic run android --prod***

i am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'componentType' of undefined
>   main.js:7.

and my app stays stuck at Splash Screen

**Here is my package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angular2-focus": "^1.0.3",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-gallery-modal": "0.0.7",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "App: An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is `build` not `run`.
Try:

```
ionic build android --release --prod
```

`run` will build and run in your attached device or emulator

Comment: if i am building it using the above command , then sign it and try installing in device,  even then it stops at splash screen,

Comment: are you using componentType anywhere?

Comment: it's just in main.js , and no where else i have used it in my app

Comment: can you add your package.json to the question?

Comment: i have added my package.json

Comment: you are in Rc4? I suggest moving to a stable version.. The latest one's package.json can be found [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: but the same package.json is working for my another app. it's being built perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138392/discussion-between-devanshsadhotra-and-suraj).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160679/how-can-i-put-an-ionic-2-modal-in-a-separate-file did you miss an export somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the "page-name.module.ts" file that is created when you use the "ionic generate page" command.
Create your pages manually and run it (ionic run android --prod) or (ionic build android --prod) again.
it worked for me.
Home they fix it soon.